# Search Scope has no content when anonymous access disabled

Tags: search, permissions, content-query-web-part, search-scope

I'm trying to setup a few search scopes for my SharePoint 2010, Publishing Site with Workflow site. The majority of the site(s) will be available to the public, so anonymous access is enabled for site collection, and all sites inherit permission from there.

However for handful of sub-sites we want to remove anonymous access, so that only logged in users can see the content (e.g. `https://myserver/myprotectedsite`). To do this I went to that site's setting page, then to site permissions, clicked 'Anonymous Access' and set the option to Nothing.

This does what I want as far as access goes, but now I'm seeing that a search scope that has a rule pointing so the site without anonymous access (e.g. `https://myserver/myprotectedsite`) contains zero content.

I've tried adding the `Default content access account` as a user with permissions to view the content of `myprotectedsite`, but still no content after a crawl.

As an aside, we're also wanting to use Content Query Web Parts that pull in info from this protected site, so if the user is not logged in these web parts are empty. Is there a way to make the content show here for anonymous users? It all seems related, hence the two questions in one.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "no content after a crawl" are you seeing that in the Search Administration page or is it the results when you attempt to perform a search as a user?

Comment: By "no content" I meant that looking at the scope in the Search Admin pages showed that the content count was "0". However, I fixed it by adding a crawl rule of "*://mysite/* and making sure I crawl as HTTP files.